# При копировании  картинки с рабочего стола NSPasteboard ведет себя странным образом?

Tags: cocoa, xcode, objective-c

При помощи CMD+C  на рабочем столе копируем н-количество раз один и тот же JPEG file.

В основном NSLog рапортует так:

```
2014-05-25 12:14:20.014 PB1[65771:303] (
    "public.file-url",
    "CorePasteboardFlavorType 0x6675726C",
    "dyn.ah62d4rv4gu8y6y4grf0gn5xbrzw1gydcr7u1e3cytf2gn",
    NSFilenamesPboardType,
    "dyn.ah62d4rv4gu8yc6durvwwaznwmuuha2pxsvw0e55bsmwca7d3sbwu",
    "Apple URL pasteboard type"
)
```

Но иногда!!! Выдает вот так:

```
2014-05-25 12:14:25.482 PB1[65771:303] (
    "public.file-url",
    "CorePasteboardFlavorType 0x6675726C",
    "dyn.ah62d4rv4gu8y6y4grf0gn5xbrzw1gydcr7u1e3cytf2gn",
    NSFilenamesPboardType,
    "dyn.ah62d4rv4gu8yc6durvwwaznwmuuha2pxsvw0e55bsmwca7d3sbwu",
    "Apple URL pasteboard type",
    "com.apple.icns",
    "CorePasteboardFlavorType 0x69636E73",
    fccc,
    "public.utf16-external-plain-text",
    "CorePasteboardFlavorType 0x75743136",
    "public.utf8-plain-text",
    NSStringPboardType,
    "public.tiff",
    "NeXT TIFF v4.0 pasteboard type"
)
```

Если честно, то хотелось бы получать всегда второй вариант(в частности NSStringPboardType). 
Но происходит все ровно наоборот.

Если увеличивать время срабатывания таймера ситуация слегка изменяется в лучшую сторону.
Но это все равно не 100%  результат.
В чем тут загвоздка? Может кто разобрался с данной проблемой?

Собственно сам код:

```
@interface AppDelegate : NSObject <NSApplicationDelegate>

{
    NSPasteboard *pasteboard;
    NSTimer *timer;
    NSInteger currient; // Текущее значение счетчика -changeCount
    NSInteger old;    // Старое значение счетчика -changeCount
}

-(void)awakeFromNib{
    pasteboard=[NSPasteboard generalPasteboard];
    currient=[pasteboard changeCount]; 
    old=currient;
   timer= [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.1 target:self selector:@selector(inPasteBoard) userInfo:nil repeats:YES]; 
}

-(void)inPasteBoard{
        currient=[pasteboard changeCount];
        if (currient!=old){
            NSLog(@"%@",[pasteboard types]);  // Не предсказуемые результаты
           // [self readPB];
            old=currient;}
    }
```